# TypeScript mapped type value depending on key

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Can I constrain the value type of a map entry depending on the item's key?

```
type Thing<T extends string = any> = {
    type: T
}

type ThingMap<T extends Thing> = {
    [K in T["type"]]: T
}

interface A {
    type: "A",
    foo: boolean,
}

interface B {
    type: "B",
}


// This compiles.
const map: ThingMap<A | B> = {
    A: { type: "A", foo: true },
    B: { type: "B" },
}

// But this also compiles, when it should not.
const map: ThingMap<A | B> = {
    A: { type: "A", foo: true },
    B: { type: "A", foo: true },
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to ensure that for a specific `K` the type of the key is not the whole union (ie `T`) but rather just the member of the union with the type `K`. You can use `Extract` to get the member of the union that has the property `type` of type `K`:

```
type Thing<T extends string = any> = {
    type: T
}

type ThingMap<T extends Thing> = {
    [K in T["type"]]:  Extract<T, { type : K }>  // Extract the union member that has { type: K }
}

interface A {
    type: "A",
    foo: boolean,
}

interface B {
    type: "B",
}


// This compiles.
const map: ThingMap<A | B> = {
    A: { type: "A", foo: true },
    B: { type: "B" },
}

// Err now
const map2: ThingMap<A | B> = {
    A: { type: "A", foo: true },
    B: { type: "A", foo: true },
}
```